# RScriptを経由したヘルプファイルの参照

Tags: r, rscript

お世話になります。
Windows7、R-3.1.2、VisualBasic.NET（.NETFramework 4.0）でRScriptを叩いてRを利用しています。

この時RScriptに対し、

Rscript -e "help(print)"

のような形でヘルプ参照を実行した所、ブラウザがhttp://127.0.0.1:21510/library/base/html/print.html を見に行きます。

しかしRのGUI環境では表示されるHTMLヘルプですがRScriptで実行するとブラウザのサーバーエラーになってしまいます。

最初はポートがおかしいのかと思い、http://www.r-bloggers.com/force-r-help-html-server-to-always-use-the-same-url-port/　を参考にポートを固定してみた所、RGUIでは問題なく動きましたがRScriptでは固定されたポートへ見に行ってサーバーエラーになっていました。

なんとかしてヘルプファイルを参照したいのですが何か解決策はございませんでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: こちらとは環境が異なりますので、参考になるのかどうか分かりませんが、`Rscript -e 'options(help_type = "html");help(print);Sys.sleep(1);'
` とすることでブラウザにヘルプを表示させる事ができました。こちらの環境は、`Ubuntu/Linux 14.04, R 3.0.2, Firefox 35.0.1` です。

Comment: heliac2001 さま
早速の回答ありがとうございました。

当方の環境で実行した所エラーなどは帰ってこないもののそもそもブラウザ自体が起動しませんでした。

一時ファイルを作り、そこにHeliac2001さんの示唆された内容を記述し-eオプションなしで一時ファイルの内容を実行すると無事に立ち上がりました。

Sys.Sleepを入れないと質問にあった内容と同様のエラーとなりますが回避方法が見つかって一安心です。

どうもありがとうございました。

Comment: コメントが役に立った様でよかったです。なお、ご自身で解決された場合には質問者の方に回答していただく様になっています。強制ではありませんが、ご協力をお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

質問者です。

コメントで頂きましたアドバイスの通り、

> options(help_type = "html");help(print);Sys.sleep(1);

を、RScriptに送る事で要望通りの結果を得ることができました。

ただし、-eオプションでの実行ではブラウザが立ち上がらなかった為、スクリプトを一時ファイルへ書き出して迂回する事で実現できました。